# Does AMP support Polymer custom elements?

Tags: polymer, amp-html, custom-element

I want to use a material-design card or Polymer's `<paper-card>` in my [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/about-amp/) page, but I couldn't find anything relevant in AMP docs. Does AMP support Polymer custom elements? If not, how could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

No, Polymer elements cannot be included in an AMP page. AMP has strict constraints in order to guarantee baseline performance characteristics, including disallowing author written JavaScript.
Since AMP HTML is only a subset of HTML and does not allow custom JavaScript, Polymer cannot be supported in AMP. Note the other way around (Polymer apps consuming AMP docs) may be [possible in the future](https://github.com/Polymer/project/issues/18#issuecomment-188325327).

Excerpt from [AMP HTML Specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec):

> AMP HTML uses a set of contributed but centrally managed and hosted custom elements to implement advanced functionality such as image galleries that might be found in an AMP HTML document. While it does allow styling the document using custom CSS, it does not allow author written JavaScript beyond what is provided through the custom elements to reach its performance goals.